# give price color in the title text

Tags: flutter, dart

how can I give color for the price in title? I have long text for the product، I need to give Different color for the price only, like this image

[image]

I used RichText but its not good

Comment: Use RichText for applying custom styles

Answer (score 1):

this below code is sample for `RichText` widget :)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Center(
              child: RichText(
                text: const TextSpan(
                  text: 'خصومات تصل علی',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                        text: ' 60% ',
                        style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,color: Colors.red)),
                    TextSpan(
                        text: ' علی ',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```